# Can I give players capes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to give a player a cape? Either so only I can see the cape, or everyone on the server can see it. Mods or texture pack editing are fine.

It is important that only a single player has the cape, rather than everyone having a cape.

Comment: This is crying out for an Edna Mode quote! https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=M68ndaZSKa8#t=126

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want [Cape Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/482814-110-capecraft-updated-to-110/). The player will need to upload their cape for you to see it, and only people with the mod will be able to see capes.

Comment: Just a quick note, you can actually  force member that wishes to join your server to have the same mods (although you might need a plugin).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this.

Comment: Try installing a mod onto the server I believe that should do it. Although it might only work with just bukkit (which is a minecraft plugin wihch is very usefull for servers!).

Comment: @Ruddie are you talking about Spoutcraft? It's a plugin that keeps player's client mods up to date with the server's mods.

Comment: I haven't heard about that, but the one I knew was not keeping the mods up to date, it simply refused players with non-up to date mods to log in.

Answer (score 1):

### Not legally

Disregarding any and all technically possibilities of adding capes to players, it's disallowed by Mojang. They explicitly asked people not to give capes to players in a [Mojang Blog post about server monetisation](https://mojang.com/2014/06/lets-talk-server-monetisation/) from June 2014:

> **You are allowed to sell in-game items so long as they don’t affect gameplay**
> [...]
> There is one exception to this rule – capes! We have a lot of fun making cool capes for extra-special members of our community and Minecon attendees. We’d like to keep them as exclusive as possible. So, yeah, **no capes please, even if you’re giving them away for free.**

(emphasis mine). Capes are meant to be highly special, given out to only the most loyal fans and members of the community.

Futher reading: [Minecraft Commercial Use](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1590522-minecraft-commercial-use)

Answer (score -1):

If you mean using vanilla minecraft the awnser would be no, you can't give people a cape. but with mond it is possibile. here are some mods you cau use

capecraft: [Link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/482814-110-capecraft-updated-to-110/)

Mineshafter: [Link](http://mineshafter.appspot.com/)

Make shure these mods are instald not only server-side but also on the client of all players.

Comment: This does not add anything to this question, you just reiterate what the other answers already stated. Furthermore, the cape mod is incredibly outdated. Mineshafter is straight-up piracy and thus not supported here on Arqade.