# Applying custom cape to badlion/lunar/laby mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had bought minecraft recently and I had used a cape and edited it, and I want to apply it to my skin.
[This is the cape that I want to upload](http://minecraft.novaskin.me/skin/4896753059/ryuga-s-cape-v2). I am fine with using any kind of launcher, the official mc launcher/badlion/lunar, but I want to apply it on my 1.8.9 as I play bedwars usually.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: please do note that you **cannot** create a custom cape for **vanilla** minecraft, so you will **have** to use some 3rd party mod to achieve this, the process of doing which will vary between which mod you want to use.

Comment: You have to be partnered with those clients to get a cape, also this is not possible via vanilla minecraft

Comment: @Topcode Thanks for your reply, could you please suggest a mod that I could add to laby mod (as I know I can't add custom mods to lunar and badlion) to use my cape?

Comment: @darthvader1925 thanks for your reply, but I don't want to be  in a partnership just yet. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @RyugaGod i know optifine has custom capes, but they are 10 dollars

Comment: @darthvader1925 wdym by that? if u mean they cost money, bc if so then ur correct but thats a weird way to word it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I give players capes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51299/can-i-give-players-capes)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Cosmetics mod for Labymod.

Comment: Can you please expand on how this mod is helpful and what exactly it does? We expect a certain level of detail in our answers.